# Error : Message Queuing failed to verify digital signature of a message sent to queue

Tags: c#, wcf, msmq

I am sending messages from a client machine to WFC service hosted in IIS on a remote machine, using `net.msmq protocol`.The queue is set as one way in WCF. The queue has authentication enable.

The client can send messages successfully but they end in the `Dead-lettler messages`. Inspecting the message using `mmc`, the sender is not authenticated (check tab sender, of message properties).

The message

> Message Queuing failed to verify digital signature of a message sent
>   to queue

appears on eventlog after 600 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find out the problem is that the sender is using a weak certificate algorithm.

To allow weak certificate algorithm i added this key to registry on the server machine:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\Security\WeakHashAlgorithms
```

and restart MSMQ service.

Reference: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773571(v=ws.10).aspx